# DataGridView scrolls to the Top if it's not the active Control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a `Form` with some `TextBoxes` on the top to `filter` my `DataGridView` at the Bottom. Everything works fine except one Behavior is bothering me.
If a `TextBox` has the `Focus` and I scroll down on my `DataGridView` and then `Click` on a `Cell`, the `DataGridView` scrolls back to the Top. But it selects the "correct" `Cell`. So if I scroll down an click on the third `Cell` from the Top, it scrolls back up and then selects the third `Cell` form the Top. How can I disable this Behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try manually setting the first displayed row when the user clicks:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem. It seems the Problem occurs, because the `DataGridView` is not the `active` `Control`. So I just select the `DataGridView` in the `MouseEnter`-`Event`.

```
private void dgvTaetigkeiten_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dgvTaetigkeiten.Select();
    }
```